# What does memset do (as used in CoreAudio)?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Really basic question here:

I've seen a bunch of CoreAudio code that uses `memset` when dealing with structs and I haven't been able to figure out why. This is from a .m ObjC file.

Here's the line from the code block below:

```
memset(&clientFormat, 0, sizeof(clientFormat));
```

//---------------

```
    AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat;
    if ( sourceFormat.mFormatID == kAudioFormatLinearPCM ) {
    clientFormat = sourceFormat;
    } else {
    memset(&clientFormat, 0, sizeof(clientFormat));
    int sampleSize = sizeof(AudioSampleType);
    clientFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    clientFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
    clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sampleSize;
    clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = sourceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket = clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame = sourceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sampleSize;
    clientFormat.mSampleRate = sourceFormat.mSampleRate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As called, it sets the memory at `&clientFormat`, with a length of `sizeof(clientFormat)`, to `0`. This is required because memory in C is not cleared to `0` after allocation with `malloc()` and most other allocation functions.

Comment: I'd like to add something (and if I am wrong please correct me):  This is necessary because otherwise if you don't explicitly set a property in clientFormat, it will have an indeterminate value (depending on what was in memory before it).  If this were, say, a pixel buffer for making a GL texture, or CGImage in which you are going to overwrite every byte immediately anyway then it is not needed.

Comment: Indeed. :) It's still good practice to `memset()` unless you know the memory will be properly filled.

Comment: ok- I get it. Without memset, all the struct fields would have to be set (to 0 or some other valid value) - Thanks! (to old pros- these are no doubt trivial questions but since they are so basic, lots of books/tutorials assume one knows this stuff)